# Сбивается бот в новом потокен aiogram

Tags: python, многопоточность, asyncio, threading

```
async def check():
    print("Check...")
    while 1:
       if ...
          await bot.send_message(...)

def startup():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    loop.run_until_complete(check())
    loop.close()
    

async def on_startup(dp): 
    threading.Thread(target=startup).start()
```

При запуске в новом потоке класса для кое какой проверки, при отправке сообщения через бота выходит ошибка

```
timeout context manager should be used inside a task
```

Как исправить?

Comment: текст ошибки приведите в вопросе, а не в его названии

Comment: тогда вы мне ответите с решением?

Comment: Нельзя использовать одни и те же asyncio-объекты из двух разных event loop'ов. Что вы пытаетесь сделать и зачем? Почему вместо простого `asyncio.create_task(check())` вы решили нагородить целый отдельный поток?

Comment: скорее всего из-за блокирующего фреймворка в мэйне.

Comment: asyncio.create_task не переводит в отдельный поток мою функцию, функцию нужно именно так, чтобы работала и проверка в функции и сам бот для пользователей

Comment: В asyncio для этого не нужен отдельный поток, достаточно простого create_task

Comment: А если же вы прям очень сильно принципиально хотите отдельный поток — значит в функции `check` избавьтесь от любых пересечений с объектами из первого event loop'а, в частности уберите использование объекта `bot`

Comment: при использовании create_task мой бот останавливается, и пользоваться им нельзя, а сама функция начинает корректно работать. а объект bot нужен, если проверка прошла успешно, он уведомляет меня

Comment: Если вы в функции check выполняете какие-то синхронные действия, то вместо того, чтобы городить отдельный поток с отдельным event loop'ом, лучше просто запустите синхронную функцию с синхронными действиями через [run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) и асинхронно дождитесь завершения её работы через обычный await

Comment: Ну и да, это самое ожидание завершения её работы можно запустить отдельно всё через тот же create_task, чтобы это ожидание не мешало работе бота

Comment: не подскажиье как это сделать?

Comment: вы наверное не так поняли, завершения данной функции не будет, там while 1. что выходит что функция будет бесконечно обновлять проверку мою, она никак не выйдет. если я что то не так понял, пришлите код

Comment: loop_in_executor можно точно так же завернуть в while 1, например

Comment: Но лучше всё-таки покажите код своей проверки, что-то я на 99% подозреваю, что там на самом деле можно всё сделать асинхронным

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138246/discussion-between-andrey-laki-and-andreymal).